# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\gamma_n} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} \mathrm{d}z$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How can the following limit be evaluated?

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\gamma_n} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} \mathrm{d}z
\end{align}

with $\gamma_n: [-\pi, 0] \to \mathbb{C}, \gamma_n(t) = \dfrac{e^{-it}}{n}$.

I know that this question is fairly similar to the question concerning the evaluation of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \mathrm{d} x$. Still, I'm interested in the concret evaluation of the limit above and haven't found something useful for that as I failed to do evaluate it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n$ is big, $e^{iz} \approx e^{i0} = 1,$ so the integral practically turns into
$$
\int_{\gamma_n} \frac{1}{z} dz
= \int_{-\pi}^{0} \frac{1}{e^{-it}/n} \frac{e^{-it}(-i)\,dt}{n}
= -i \int_{-\pi}^{0} dt
= -i\pi
.
$$

You just need to quantify the difference and show that it vanishes in the limit.

Comment: I wonder why the downvote.

Comment: @metamorphy. Perhaps because I didn't quantify the difference. Could also be someone who have been hurt by something I have written about his/hers answer somewhere.